# Unity 4.6, run in debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

How can I run the current game inside the Unity editor in debug mode - as in preprocessor variable DEBUG will be true/enabled for scripts. I normally have a lot of:

```
#if DEBUG
dostuffonlyindebuglikegetalotofmoneyingame();
#else
// release mode
#endif
```

scattered around my projects. Using Unity 4.6 RC3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have global #defines with one of these methods:

1. build settings, per platform
   [image]

   also available via build script: 
   [PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup.html)
2. [Global Custom Defines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)
3. For debug, maybe a check for `UNITY_EDITOR` is enough?

Comment: This should be enough, thanks. Just one thing, something like 1. but for the Unity editor? I want to set what defines the unity editor will have.

Comment: Don't think there is one, but you can use `#if MY_DEBUG || UNITY_EDITOR`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/Debug-isDebugBuild.html

Not sure yet but it seems not very good because:

- As this is a runtime check, it would probably get debug code into release builds... affecting performance as well as stability and your reputation ;-)
- The only supported mode in the Unity "Game" mode is the Debug one. This really sucks. Deploying to devices to test release builds just takes too long time because deployment is SLOW, at least on my box. :-(
- Any #if DEBUG etc you wrote so far can't be used. You would have to replace that with the runtime calls Debug.isDebugBuild ... not pretty.

Not sure if Debug.isDebugBuild is removed on release builds or not... if not, Unity sucks :-)

That said, this might be the only option... poor us.